# Я начинающий, работаю с Inline кнопками на aiogram и не могу понять где здесь ошибка

Tags: python, aiogram

````
inline_btn_lifegamet = types.InlineKeyboardButton("1", callback_data="lifegamet")
inline_btn_lifegamed = types.InlineKeyboardButton("2", callback_data="lifegamed")
inline_btn_startlifegame = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1).add(inline_btn_lifegamet,
                                                                       inline_btn_lifegamed)


@dp.message_handler(commands="lifegame")
async def cmd_startlifegame(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Выбирай!", reply_markup=inline_btn_startlifegame)


@dp.message_handler(lambda c: c.data == "lifegamet")
async def d(message: types.Message):
    button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Продолжить", callback_data="restart")
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(button1)
    await message.answer(await get_random_question(), reply_markup=keyboard)


@dp.callback_query_handler()
async def ycallback(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    if callback_query.data == "restart":
        await bot.delete_message(chat_id=callback_query.message.chat.id, message_id=callback_query.message.message_id)
        await cmd_startlifegame(callback_query.message)


@dp.message_handler(lambda c: c.data == "lifegamed")
async def d(message: types.Message):
    button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Продолжить", callback_data="restart")
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(button1)
    await message.answer(await get_random_action(), reply_markup=keyboard)


@dp.callback_query_handler()
async def ycallback(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    if callback_query.data == "restart":
        await bot.delete_message(chat_id=callback_query.message.chat.id, message_id=callback_query.message.message_id)
        await cmd_startlifegame(callback_query.message)


async def get_random_question():
    with open("D:/.........t") as f:
        content = f.readlines()
    content = [x.strip() for x in content]
    return random.choice(content)


async def get_random_action():
    with open("D:/........") as f:
        content = f.readlines()
    content = [x.strip() for x in content]
    return random.choice(content)```
````

Comment: Желательно указывать код ошибки.

Comment: Почему вы решили, что здесь есть ошибка?

Comment: ошибку не выдает, но и не работает